# How to run maintenance plan task on success of two other tasks

Tags: sql-server, sql, ssms

I need to run the maintenance plan task on success of two other tasks and only after those tasks have completed. At the moment task2 starts straight away after one of the other two completes and it's not waiting for them both to finish.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmb7D.png)

Answer (score 0):

SSMS' Maintenance Plan Wizard will only let you serialize your sequence of tasks, but the Maintenance Plan Designer will let you setup the AND condition you're looking to meet before starting the 3rd task.  For more info, refer to the [SSMS "Precedent Contraints" documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/precedence-constraints). An excerpted screenshot of the particular section pertaining to your scenario is below. Alternatively, you can also write a custom script.

[image: SSMS Precedent Constraints]

Comment: This is how I thought that it should work, but after I have created a Maintenance plan using this logic it just doesn't wait for both tasks to finish. I had to use WAITFOR DELAY  to force third task to wait until other two finish running. Possibly a bug? Or precedence constraints work differently in SSIS than in Maintenance plan(Under SSMS Management folder).